# How to call a function and print it within quotes?

Tags: python, double-quotes

I would like to print two parameters of a function inside double quotes, something like this

```
def convert_to_currency(a,b):
    print (a,b)
convert_to_currency("$",350)
```

The output that I am getting is $350.

But, I would like to get the output as "$350".

How do I do this with this function?

Comment: Why do you need the quotes?

Comment: Is the problem the missing quotes or the inherent space between the dollar symbol and amount?

Comment: I would expect a function called "convert_to_currency" to return an instance of some type that represents currency, not just print its arguments. Where is the "conversion"?

Answer (score 4):

For Python 3.6+, use f strings.

Since you are requiring two inputs, I'll borrow from @robert-axe response:

```
def convert_to_currency(a, b):
    print(f'"{a}{b}"')


convert_to_currency("$", 350)
```

Note the set of single and double quotes here. This will print the string with quotes. You can use a different currency symbol in `a` still.

Comment: Note: additional edit for PEP8 white space for readability.

Comment: Yup, I would edit the function directly to format the output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use different quotes.

```
value = '$350'
print(f'"{value}"')
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use backslashes to cancel out (disable) the double qoute, like this.

```
def convert_to_currency(a, b):
    print ("\"", a, b, "\"")
convert_to_currency("$", 350)
```